# Why is this not a lattice??

Tags: lattice-orders

The solution says it's not a lattice. I can't figure out why the following is not a lattice...I think I checked the meet (join) of almost every pair.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at $d$ and $e$: $i$ and $j$ are both minimal (**not** minimum = least!) upper bounds of $\{d,e\}$, and they’re not comparable, so $d$ and $e$ have no **least** upper bound.

Comment: Ah! It's obvious now that you pointed it out. Much appreciated.

Comment: @epsilon-delta: You’re welcome. It did take me a while to find it, though I knew that $f$ had to be involved, since if you remove that dot and just leave the $bj$ connection, you *do* get a lattice.

Comment: Yes you're absolutely right, I came that conclusion when I removed $f$ but I totally missed the relation $d < f <j$.